# Spring boot + elasticsearch prefix adding doen't work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have this entity:

```
@Data
@Document(indexName = "foo.user")
public class ElUser {

    @Id
    private  String id;

    @Field(type = FieldType.Text)
    private String fullName;
}
```

And this Repository:

```
@Repository
interface ElasticsearchUserRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<ElUser, String> {
List<ElUser> findAllByFullNameIsLike(String name);
}
```

And it works fine. But I want to use a prefix like this(`.withPathPrefix("foo")`):

```
@EnableElasticsearchRepositories
@Configuration
public class ElasticsearchConfig extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @Override
    public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {

        final ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder()
                .connectedTo("localhost:9200")
                .withPathPrefix("foo")
                .build();

        return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
    }
}
```

And remove it from entity:

```
@Document(indexName = "user")
```

But I get an exception:

```
org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.NoSuchIndexException: Index [foo] not found.; nested exception is [foo] ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=index_not_found_exception, reason=no such index [foo]]]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path prefix you can configure is not a prefix for the index name like *foo* in *foo.user*, it's for the path in the URL which might be needed for some routing/proxying/dispatching software between the application and Elasticsearch.

Let's imagine you have two Elasticsearch clusters at `foo:9200` and `bar:9200` and there is a nginx proxy in front of them at `proxy:8080` which will route an request to `proxy:8080/foo/abc` to `foo:9200/abc` and `proxy:8080/bar/abc` to `bar:9200/abc`, then you would configure you client to connect to `proxy:8080` with a pathPrefix of *foo*.

So it's not for the use case you have.

**Edit:**

I have an example of how to provide an index prefix in my [blog post "How to provide a dynamic index name in Spring Data Elasticsearch using SpEL"](https://www.sothawo.com/2020/07/how-to-provide-a-dynamic-index-name-in-spring-data-elasticsearch-using-spel/), in the section *Use a value from the application configuration*, that might fit your needs.

_

Comment: Ok, Thank you! Do you know how can I do what I wanted? Extract foo from @Document(indexName = "foo.user") and hold it in properties

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But the solution is a crutch. I need to add SpEL sentences to each @Document. Somebody can miss it. What about refactoring? And I have strange behavior - `@Document(indexName = "#{@appPropertiesService.getElasticsearchProperties().getIndexName()}", createIndex = false)` throws exception `Consider defining a bean named 'appPropertiesService' in your configuration.` but using of implementation works fine - `@Document(indexName = "#{@defaultAppPropertiesService.getElasticsearchProperties().getIndexName()}", createIndex = false)`